# How do I compare two queries by two columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, compare

What's the best way to compare two queries by two columns? these are my tables:

**This table shows exam questions**

```
idEvaluation | Question | AllowMChoice | CorrectAnswer|
1                1            0             3 
1                2            1             4
1                2            1             5
1                3            0             9
```

**This table shows a completed exam**

```
  idExam| idEvaluation | Question | ChosenAnswer|
    25        1              1            2
    25        1              2            4
    25        1              2            5
    25        1              3            8
```

I have to calculate the percentage of correct Answers, considering to certain questions may allow multiple selection.

Correct Answers / Total Answers * 100

thanks for your tips!

Comment: Is a multi choice answer correct if all the correct options are picked, or if any of the correct options are picked? (so in your example of question 2, is (4,5) scored as 1 correct answer or 2, and would (3,5) be regarded as one correct answer (as 5 is correct)?

Comment: a multi choice answer is correct if all the correct options are picked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will show you a listing of Questions and whether or not they were answered correctly.

```
select
    A.Question,
    min(1) as QuestionsCount,
    -- if this evaluates to null, they got A) the answer wrong or B) this portion of the answer wrong
    -- we use MIN() here because we want to mark multi-answer questions as wrong if any part of the answer is wrong. 
    min(case when Q.idEvaluation IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) as QuestionsCorrect
from
    ExamAnswers as A
    left join ExamQuestions as Q on Q.Question = A.Question and Q.CorrectAnswer = A.ChosenAnswer
group by
    A.Question -- We group by question to merge multi-answer-questions into 1
```

Output Confirmed:

[image]

Note, the columns are intentionally named this way, as they are to be included as a subquery in part-2 below.

---

This code will give you the test score.

```
select
    sum(I.QuestionsCorrect) as AnswersCorrect,
    sum(I.QuestionsCount) as QuestionTotal,
    convert(float,sum(I.QuestionsCorrect)) / sum(I.QuestionsCount) as PercentCorrect -- Note, not sure of the cast-to-float syntax for MySQL
from
    (select
        A.Eval,
        A.Question,
        min(1) as QuestionsCount,
        min(case when Q.idEvaluation IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) as QuestionsCorrect
    from
        ExamAnswers as A
        left join ExamQuestions as Q on Q.Question = A.Question and Q.CorrectAnswer = A.ChosenAnswer
    where 
        A.Eval = 25
    group by
        A.Question, A.Eval) as I
group by        
    I.Eval
```

Output Confirmed:

[image]

This will communicate the general concept. Your column names `idEvaluation` and `Eval` are difficult for me to understand, but I'm sure you can adjust the code above to suit your purposes.

Note, I did this in sql server, but I used fairly basic SQL functionality, so it should translate to MySQL well.

Comment: eval was edited as idExam, this is an already finished exam.  
idEvaluation is just a primary key of each exam. Thanks for your tip, Im going to test this.

Comment: min(case when Q.idEvaluation IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) as QuestionsCorrect. I don't understand this code, idEvaluation cannot be NULL because is a FK pointing to an exam

Comment: Check the `ON Clause` - It joins on Q.Question = A.Question ALSO on Q.CorrectAnswer = A.ChosenAnswer; therefore, Q.idEvaluation will be NULL when that On Clause does not evaluate to true. That's how I check to see if there was a correct answer or not in such a way that it works for Multiple choice questions or regular questions.